# terraform 12 nested mapping

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

just want to ask for your help on how I can my **main.tf** file possibly take the value of **"labrador"** from the nested variables from **variables.tfvars**

**variables.tfvars**

```
PETS = {
  dog = {
    indoor                          = "poodle"
    outdoor                         = "labrador"
    others                          = "bulldog"

  }
  cat = {
    indoor                          = "siamese"
    outdoor                         = "persian"
    others                          = "bengal"

  }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable PETS { type = map }
```

**main.tf**

```
module "lambda-module" {
  source                        = "../../module/lambda-module"
  PETS                          = var.PETS[var.TYPE[var.BREED]]
}
```

I would like to execute it and take the proper values and assign to the the lambda-module using this command:

```
terraform plan -var-file=variables.tf -var "TYPE=dog" -var "BREED=outdoor"
```

however I'm getting this issue:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 3, in module "lambda-module":

3:   PETS          = var.PETS[var.TYPE[var.BREED]]
    |----------------
    | var.TYPE is "dog"
    | var.BREED is "outdoor"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in:
`var.PETS[var.TYPE[var.BREED]]`
that should be:
`var.PETS[var.TYPE][var.BREED]`

Here is an example:

```
variable PETS {
  type = map
  default = {
    "dog" = {
      indoor  = "poodle"
      outdoor = "labrador"
      others  = "bulldog"
    },
    "cat" = {
      indoor  = "siamese"
      outdoor = "persian"
      others  = "bengal"
    }
  }
}

variable TYPE {
  type = string
}

variable BREED {
  type = string
}


output "TYPE_BREED" {
  value = var.PETS[var.TYPE][var.BREED]
}
```

```
terraform apply -var "TYPE=dog" -var "BREED=outdoor"

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

TYPE_BREED = labrador
```

```
terraform apply -var "TYPE=cat" -var "BREED=indoor"

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

TYPE_BREED = siamese
```